# Could inhomogeneties and/or topological defects break the fundamental symmetries of the universe?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, symmetry, symmetry-breaking, cosmic-string

I have heard that some types of inhomogeneties and topological defects (like cosmic strings) in cosmology have been proposed to be able to break fundamental symmetries of nature such as the Poincaré, Lorentz, diffeomorphism CPT, spatial/time translational...etc symmetries... However, I have not been able to find any references about this. Is this true? Is there anything about this?

Comment: Even a humble blob of dust will break many of those symmetries in essentially the same sense that a cosmic string does. That is, in the presence of such a blob the background for other things is no longer uniform. But if you include the blob as part of your system then you get the symmetry back again (in the Lagrangian that is).

Comment: @AndrewSteane but could one always include that blob as part of your system? Or would there be situations where they would inevitably break all the symmetries I mentioned?

Comment: I don't know but I suspect it is a case where one would have the option of treating it either way. The value of symmetry-style arguments is the insight they bring.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/748785/2451 and links  therein.